# how to set accuracy when using csv writer in python

Tags: python, csv

I have a float variable, obj["time"], which represents the unix time, previously I write the result to a text file, so I could use

```
  fd_out.write("%.6f\n" %(obj["time"]))
```

to force the result to have 6 decimal. But now I want to print the result into csv file instead, so I used:

```
  writer.writerow((obj["time"]))
```

the result only have 2 decimal by default, how could I change it?

Comment: this was answered earlier:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982642/specifying-formatting-for-csv-writer-in-python

Comment: Shouldn't that be `writer.writerow( (obj['time'],) )` # ie, a one element tuple?

Comment: Where are you seeing that it only has two decimal places?  When I use `csv.writer` I get all the digits that are in my input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using an intermediate format should solve your problem, like this example:

```
writer.writerow(("%.6f" % obj["time"], ))
```

Answer (score 1):

When you were writing directly to the file, you did a formatting operation to convert the float variable to a string with the desired number of digits. You can do the exact same thing for the CSV writer.

```
writer.writerow("%.6f" %(obj["time"]))
```

As pointed out in the comments you'll need to leave out the newline, since the CSV writer will add that for you.

Comment: @OttoAllmendinger, thanks. It's so easy to miss the simple obvious things.

Answer (score 1):

from the earlier answer at [Specifying formatting for csv.writer in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982642/specifying-formatting-for-csv-writer-in-python):

```
class TypedWriter:
    """
    A CSV writer which will write rows to CSV file "f",
    which uses "fieldformats" to format fields.
    """

    def __init__(self, f, fieldnames, fieldformats, **kwds):
        self.writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames, **kwds)
        self.formats = fieldformats

    def writerow(self, row):
        self.writer.writerow(dict((k, self.formats[k] % v) 
                                  for k, v in row.iteritems()))

    def writerows(self, rows):
        for row in rows:
            self.writerow(row)
```